# Error when edit non string property when Objects Binded To TcxGridTableView using DSharp

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a class object

```
TContact = class(TObject)
  private
    FChild: TContact;
    FLastname: string;
    FFirstname: string;
    FAge: Integer;
    procedure SetFirstname(const Value: string);
    procedure SetLastname(const Value: string);
  public
    constructor Create(AFirstname: string = ''; ALastname: string = ''; AChild :
        TContact = nil; AAge : Integer = 10);
    property Child: TContact read FChild write FChild;
    property Firstname: string read FFirstname write SetFirstname;
    property Lastname: string read FLastname write SetLastname;
    property Age: Integer read FAge write FAge;
end;
```

I want to display some objects into TcxGridTableView. Here is my code to display some objects on TcxGridTableView

```
var
  lFather: TContact;
  list: IList<TObject>;
  lJon: TContact;
  lMother: TContact;
begin
  list := TObservableCollection<TObject>.Create();

  lJon    := TContact.Create('Jericho', 'Doe', TContact.Create('No Child'),8);
  lFather := TContact.Create('John', 'Doe', lJon, 48);
  lMother :=  TContact.Create('Nancy', 'More', lJon, 45 );

  list.Add(lJon);
  list.Add(lFather);
  list.Add(lMother);

  prescontactpresenter.View.ItemsSource := list.AsList;
end;
```

Everything is running well. I can modify the value of FirstName and Lastname. But when I Modify the value Age property directly on age column, i get the following error :

[image]

But when i bind Age property to Tedit, i can modify its value. has any one know how it can be that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PropertiesClass of that column (to lets say TcxSpinEditProperties). That can be done after setting the ItemsSource. Otherwise the default column properties is TextEdit which will send the values as string which will not be converted automatically to Integer in the binding.

Another way is to turn off the `UseColumnDefinitions` property in the presenter and create all columns yourself.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still generates Invalid Typecast AV. Here is my code : prescontactpresenter.View.ItemsSource := list.AsList;
  cxGridTableGrid1TableView1.Columns[3].PropertiesClass := TcxSpinEditProperties;

Answer (score 0):

I Found the workaround. I modified unit DSharp.DevExpress.PresenterDataSource

```
procedure TGridViewPresenterDataSource.SetValue(
  ARecordHandle: TcxDataRecordHandle; AItemHandle: TcxDataItemHandle;
  const AValue: Variant);
var
  LItemTemplate: IDataTemplate;
begin
  LItemTemplate := FPresenter.GetItemTemplate(ARecordHandle);
  // remarked bagus BP
  //LItemTemplate.SetText(ARecordHandle, Integer(AItemHandle), VarToStrDef(AValue, ''));
  LItemTemplate.SetValue(ARecordHandle, Integer(AItemHandle), TValue.FromVariant(AValue));
end;
```

I tried with String, Integer, Float, and DateType data type and the result is OK

Comment: @Stefan : What do you think about my answer ? tq

Comment: If that is your source code then you are using master and not the latest version which is in the spring4d-compatibility branch.

Comment: @Stefan : I downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/get/ad7c5983505f.zip

Comment: @Stefan, I downloaded from spring4d-compatibility and the result is the same. It also generate AV